# Issues in importing xlsx file with country column in R

Tags: r, excel, import

I am importing an .xlsx file in R and I am encountering issues with a country field.
I managed country fields multiple times and this never happened. I noticed it's the first time my Excel displays country column this way:

[image: view Excel]

[view Excel 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bulw4.png)

I tried to import the .xlsx file using both read_xlsx and read_excel functions but both resulted in a empty column (all country entries are converted in NA).
Do you have any suggestion on the cause of this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Try export as .csv from excel, then `read.csv`.

Comment: That’s because your column is Excel’s [“Geography” data type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-geographic-location-data-287b4cf2-3d7d-4bc1-b412-3d00f45dbbd6) rather than plain text — as indicated by the little map symbols. If possible, converting to plain text in Excel before importing to R will be easier than figuring out how to import this data type.